# FactoryGirl association from inherited factory

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I am new to testing in Rails, and am having great difficulty testing my associations. I'd like to simply have factories for confirmed users with various roles that I can create in my specs. I'd like to simply have the ability to `user = create(:user_superadmin)` or `user = create(:user_accountadmin)`, but am having difficulty doing so.

Below is the error I'm encountering when running my spec:

```
Failure/Error: user = create(:user_superadmin)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for :user_superadmin:Symbol
```

Please see my code below:

**factories/role.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :role_superadmin, class: Role do
    name 'SuperAdmin'
    description 'Lorem ipsum...'
  end
end
```

**factories/user.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(8) }
    password_confirmation { password }

    factory :confirmed_user do
      confirmed_at Time.zone.now

      factory :user_superadmin do
        association :role, factory: role_superadmin
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec**

```
it 'should be a superadmin user' do
  user = create(:user_superadmin)
  expect(user.super_admin?).to be_truthy
end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of the :user_superadmin, try this association:

`association :role, factory: :role_superadmin`

Notice that :role_superadmin must be a symbol as well so FactoryGirl can find the proper factory.

Comment: No problem. When I was starting out with FactoryGirl I found this set of tips  by Arjan van der Gaag helpful: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/factory_girl_tips.html